# how to run apk file in android

Tags: android, apk

- First get the Android SDK and unzip it somewhere on your hard drive
- Add SDK_ROOT to your system variables pointing to /tools folder under the sdk
- Run the emulator
- Copy the apk file to /tools folder

i followed above this procedure but i didn't get result ,
what can i do ?

Comment: whats the problem you are facing

Comment: What result were you expecting? How is this programming related?

Answer (score 0):

Copying an apk to the tools folder accomplishes nothing, you need to *install* it on the real or emulated android device, using a command such as

adb install someappliction.apk

Comment: Hai Chris Stratton, I already follow this method, but didn't work can u explain clear (adb install someappliction.apk)

Comment: hai chris stratton...Thanks so much but this steps are already follow but i didn't get ...

Comment: Please re-read the documentation concerning installing applications with ADB or alternatively that for debugging something that you have built in eclipse.